# Pie Chart not showing anything on Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller, charts

The pie chart showing nothing but a blank page. Please find codes in the attached screenshots[image]

```
<apex:page standardController="case" extensions="CaseController"  >
    <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="My Pie Chart"/>
    <apex:chart height="450" width="550" data="{!case}">
         <apex:pieSeries dataField="type" labelField="Case Status">   
        </apex:pieSeries>
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example of a pie chart that will display.

The key thing to check when working with `apex:chart` is your browser's console as most errors are reported there from the JavaScript that renders the chart. From that you will discover that:

- the `labelField` and `dataField` values are case sensitive; ensure you match the casing of the field names exactly (e.g. check them in the Setup UI)
- the field nominated by `dataField` must be a number so the logic can decide how wide to make the pie wedge
- the `dataField` field must be set in every record (and probably also the `labelField` field)

Controller:

```
public class Tmp {
    public Account[] getAccounts() {
        Account[] accounts = [select Name, NumberOfEmployees from Account order by Name];
        for (Account a : accounts) {
            // All values must be set but this field is optional default where not set
            if (a.NumberOfEmployees == null) a.NumberOfEmployees = 0;
        }
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="Tmp">
    <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="My Pie Chart"/>
    <apex:chart height="450" width="550" data="{!accounts}">
         <apex:pieSeries labelField="Name" dataField="NumberOfEmployees"/>   
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Unless you have a specific need that `StandardSetController` helps with, I suggest you remove that from your code. The data you want to display may not be immediately available and so require an [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) or some other processing logic to create it.